# How can i detect closest parent using variable inside JavaSript Class method

Tags: javascript, html, es6-class

I have two navigation and when i click on the menus, a border should be add to the parent. I did the navigation using ES6 class. I need only one object to make this functionality. Now it is working because i hardcoded the class name as follows `e.target.closest(".one").style.border="2px solid green";` here i used `.one` instead of it, i need variable which needs to detect the closest class `.one`. Hopes my explanation make sense for everyone. If not, ask me i'll be eloborate more. Hopes anyone can help me. Following is my code. Thanks in Advance!

```js
class Navigation{
constructor(parent) {
this.parent= document.querySelectorAll(parent);
}

addBorder(){
let li = this.parent.forEach((elem)=>{
elem.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
e.target.closest(".one").style.border="2px solid green";
})
})
}

};

let one = new Navigation(".one");
one.addBorder();
```

```css
    nav {font-family:arial;width:15rem;}
    nav ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:1rem;padding-left:.5rem;}
    nav ul a {color:#777;text-decoration:none;padding:.5rem;}
```

```html
<nav class="one">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<nav class="one">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this along the lines of what you are trying to do? Added a new method to navigate up the DOM to find the parent as specified in the constructor. From that obtain it's class and proceed as you were....more or less

```js
class Navigation {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = document.querySelectorAll(parent);
  };

  find(e) {
    let n = e.target;
    while (n.tagName.toLowerCase() != this.parent.item(0).tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      if (n.nodeName === 'BODY') return false;
      n = n.parentNode;
    }
    return n;
  };

  addBorder() {
    this.parent.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        let _cn = this.find(e).className;
        e.target.closest(`.${_cn}`).classList.add('banana')

      })
    })
  }

};

let one = new Navigation("nav");
one.addBorder();
```

```css
nav {
  font-family: arial;
  width: 15rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

nav ul a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}


/* only to aid visualisation */
.banana {
  border: 5px solid green;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav class="one" id='a'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<nav class="one" id='b'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi @Professor Abronsius, Many Thanks for giving me solution and a method where i can study more things!